# Parse object not editing successfully

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm writing a function that queries Parse for a `matchCenterItem` object associated with the respective user, and then editing certain properties of that object. When the query is made, the response (`results`) is returned in this form:

```
<matchCenterItem: 0x7f84e2c1a4b0, objectId: Je1VxP7dPw, localId: (null)> {
    categoryId = 9355;
    itemCondition = Used;
    itemLocation = US;
    maxPrice = 350;
    minPrice = 250;
    parent = "<PFUser: 0x7f84e2c20c10, objectId: kfEHfG4FUD>";
    searchTerm = "iphone 5 unlocked";
}
```

I then want to update the fields with the params being sent. When the function is run, it prints out `'MatchCenterItem successfully edited!'`, and yet when I check the dashboard, the item hasn't been updated at all. Am I missing something? Full code is below.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("editMatchCenter", function(request, response) {

  var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
  var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);

  query.contains('searchTerm', request.params.searchTerm);
  query.equalTo('parent', Parse.User.current())

  query.first().then(function(results) {

    results.set('minPrice', request.params.minPrice);
    results.set('maxPrice', request.params.maxPrice);
    results.set('itemCondition', request.params.itemCondition);
    results.set('itemLocation', request.params.itemLocation);
    results.save();

  });

  response.success('MatchCenterItem successfully edited!');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to this and it works now:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("editMatchCenter", function(request, response) {

  var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
  var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);

  query.contains('searchTerm', request.params.searchTerm);
  query.equalTo('parent', Parse.User.current())

  query.first({
    success: function(results) {

      results.set('minPrice', request.params.minPrice);
      results.set('maxPrice', request.params.maxPrice);
      results.set('itemCondition', request.params.itemCondition);
      results.set('itemLocation', request.params.itemLocation);
      results.save();

      response.success('MatchCenterItem successfully edited!');

    },
    error: function() {
      response.error('MatchCenterItem NAAAAT successfully edited!');
    }
  });

});
```